# hyperlink column Name through Xsl

Tags: sharepoint, xslt, xslt-1.0

I have document Library where the ColumnName is Name and the data is hyperlinked to Documents.
    I want to access this through xslt.
    [image: List appears like given below]
    [image: After applying xsl should appear like this but right now i am able to populate the Name.Where as my current requirement is. it should be hyperlinked to the corresponding document]

```
My xsl code is given below:
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
              xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
              xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt"
              exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl" xmlns:ddwrt2="urn:frontpage:internal">
  <xsl:output method='html' indent='yes'/>    
  <xsl:template match='dsQueryResponse'>
    <table cellpadding="10" cellspacing="0" border="1" style="padding:25px;">    
      <tr>
        <td colspan='2'>
          <b style="font-size:25px;">NewsLetter List</b>
        </td>        
      </tr>
      <xsl:apply-templates select='Rows/Row'/>
    </table>
  </xsl:template> 

  <xsl:template match='Row'>   
    <tr>
      <td>
        <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="1">
          <tr>
            <td>
              <b>
                <img src="../PublishingImages/newsletter_icon.png" width="20px" height="20px"></img>
              </b>
              </td>
            <td>
                <xsl:value-of select="@Name"/>
            </td>
          </tr>

      </table>     
      </td>
    </tr>    
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: So what's your question?

Comment: my question is i want to hyperlink these data if u see in the image(AJAX Q.docx and so on).If i click on those data it should navigate me to the corresponding documents.

Comment: Do you have an example of the XML that is being fed into the XSLT?

Comment: there is no xml I have used out of box feature on list.there is an option in ecb menu called edit web part- under which we get miscellaneous Heading - under miscellaneous we find xsl link -where i ve linked the xslt file link.it automatically applies the format to list.

Comment: Some one please help:(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the source XML contains the same attributes that are available by default, could you try replacing this:

```
<td>
  <xsl:value-of select="@Name"/>
</td>
```

With this:

```
<td>
  <a href="{@FileRef}">
    <xsl:value-of select="@Name"/>
  </a>
</td>
```